# Content goes above footer

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the page there is pagination link under the image. When there is a lot of pages ( ~60 ) they go above the footer section. I've tried to add `<div class="clear:both;></div>` and `<div class="clearfix;></div>` right after ` but the right side goes under the image also with clear.

[Here is sample Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/706bcaxn/10/)
Any ideas how this can be fixed?
[image]

This is what happen. Black line is the footer. Just this pagination doesn't extend the main part and goes above footer.

This is pagination css which cause the problem.

```
.pagination {padding: 3px;margin: 0px;height: 30px;display: block;text-align: center;}
.pagination a{display: inline-block; list-style: none;  padding: 2px; margin-right: 1px; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 30px; text-align: center; background: #4CC2AF; line-height: 25px;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;}
.pagination .active {display: inline-block;list-style: none;padding: 3px;margin-right: 1px;width: 30px;text-align: center;line-height: 25px;background-color: #666666;cursor:inherit;}
```

Comment: If you use clearfix is because you have this class in your css and

    <div class="clear:both;></div>

is wrong

    <div style="clear:both"></div>

And sorry but i can´t reply your problem.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I have added also image what exactly happen.

Comment: Also I don't have clearfix or clear:both in css.

Comment: @JordanVit Do you have html/body height: 100%? or do you have footer/pagination position: absolute?

Comment: No, I don't have height: 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have a fixed height, and the children are overflowing on the Y axis.

try using `height: auto;` on the parent element.

Comment: well here's the reason, the parent element is fixed at let's say 25px. When the page number boxes create a second or third row, the 3 children rows exceed this 25px container. However, you can still see the children elements even though they bleed over the bottom bounds of the parent. try putting `overflow-y: scroll;` on the parent to get a visual. I bet that will help you grasp the concept :)

Comment: Accepted and voted. Last question but why this happen even when this pagination <div> is inside the parent div. I mean I can put 1k images on parent this and it will expand on height. But when I put the pagination inside doesn't expand. This is what confuse me. Thank's for the help.

Comment: The parent of the pagination div only sees the direct children elements height. So if the pagination div has a static height of 25px, that is all the parent div sees. the parent does not see that the children of the pagination div actually take up 100px.